# JSOn inner child attribute undefined index error

Tags: php, json

This is a sample of my Json

```
{
   "164616":{
      "competitors":{
         "950053":{
            "Name":"Hookinn",
            "Jockey":"L PILLAR(A)",
            "DetailedPricing":{
               "winTotePlus":false,
               "placeTotePlus":false,
               "placePrices":{
                  "2":0,
                  "12":0
               },
               "RisaSilkID":1551
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This is my code .

```
$string = file_get_contents(@"D:/test.json");
$json_a=json_decode($string,true);

    foreach ($json_a as $root_element => $childnode) {
        foreach( $childnode as $cKey => $subChild) {
            foreach( $subChild as $cKey2 => $subChild2) {
             echo($subChild2['Name']);  
         echo("<br>");
           foreach($subChild2['DetailedPricing'] as $compKey => $compVal) {
        //   echo($compVal['placeTotePlus']); echo("<br>");}

          }
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to get Name attribute using subChild2['Name'] but i when i am trying to access placeTotePlus attribute which is inside DetailedPricing array then i am getting undefined index error. What i am doing wrong? and i also want to get placePrices values as well.

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$subChild2['DetailedPricing']['placeTotePlus']` instead of a `foreach()`?

Comment: yup but i am not getting any value because it is boolean?

Comment: Define what to echo when it is a boolean as you can't echo a boolean... `echo $compVal['placeTotePlus'] ? 'Your "true" option' : 'Your "false" option';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

```
$string = json_decode($string, true);
foreach($string as $item => $comp) {

    foreach($comp as $key =>$users) {
        foreach($users as $derp=>$user) {
            var_dump($user['DetailedPricing']['placeTotePlus']);
        }
    }
}
```

Which returns:

```
bool(false)
```

[**`Example`**](https://eval.in/166200)

The reason it doesn't print anything is because it is a boolean. You can test (*as stated in the comments*) something like this:

```
(!$users['DetailedPricing']['placeTotePlus']) ? 'Its false' : 'Its true';
```

---

In response to your comment, you'd use [**`isset()`**](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.isset.php)

```
if(!isset($user['DetailedPricing']['PlaceTotPlus'])) {
    print 'nothing';
}
```

Comment: AND In some data placeTotePlus does not exist and it is throwing undefined index. I just need to print "nothing" where placeTotePlus key desnot exist

Comment: @user3754380 see edit for how to check if it exists.

Comment: well it is not printing anything when placeTotePlus does not exist

Comment: @user3754380 could you update your question to show said code please?

Comment: actually i have figured out myself and all good now thanks Darren